# convergence in measure imples integrability

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, pointwise-convergence

If $f_n$ converges in measure to $f$ on a the set $E$,and $\int_E{|f_n|} \leq M$ for all $n$.
Claim: $f$ is integrable.

I think by Riesz theorem there is a subsequence that convergence pointwise to $f$, but then can I apply Bounded convergence theorem as integrals of $f_n$ bounded then $f_n$ is bounded as well?

Comment: Do you mean $\int_E |f|<\infty$?

Comment: You can use Fatou's Lemma to justify integrability.

Comment: No, $\int f_n$ bounded does not imply $f_n$ bounded.

Comment: @Jose27, Thank you I proved by Fatou's Lemma!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that, convergence in measure $\implies$ $\{f_n\}$ is cauchy in measure. Therefore, it has a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ such that $f_{n_k} \to f$ almost uniformly. Now, apply Fatou's to $\{f_{n_k}\}$ to show that $f$ is integrable.